# MongoDB Atlas not connecting from Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-atlas, k3s

I'm a complete beginner to k8s, this is my first deployment. I have a NodeJS server that connects to MongoDB Atlas. I deployed it to k8s but it doesn't connect to Atlas.

I'm getting the following error in pod logs

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. 
One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. 
Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:819:32)
    at /myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:10
    at /myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1224:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:378:20)
    at Object.module.exports.connect (/myapp/config/db.js:5:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/myapp/index.js:75:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:513:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    at promiseOrCallback (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1224:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:378:20)
    at Object.module.exports.connect (/myapp/config/db.js:5:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/myapp/index.js:75:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:513:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-tszcvnh-shard-00-01.efxgtyi.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-tszcvnh-shard-00-02.efxgtyi.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-tszcvnh-shard-00-00.efxgtyi.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-ew9q6w-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

I tried setting the `dnsPolicy` to `default` and `ClusterFirstWithHostNet` both didn't work.

My Atlas Network access is as follows, I've added a lot of possible ip's in hope of getting 1 running
[image: Network Access]

The whitened out ip is my `servers-public-ip/32`

There are API calls to other public API's like weathermap in the app and they work fine.

I'm using `k3s` binary on a `Debian 10` machine.

The `service` type is `LoadBalancer`.

Following is my `Deployment` config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-name
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: some-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: some-name
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: some-name
        image: me/myimg
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          env-variables-here
```

Following is my `Service` config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: some-name
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30001
```

On doing `cat /etc/resolv.conf` I get the following

[image: this]

Comment: Try to resolve the mongoDB Atlas servers inside container. Does it resolve?
Do you connect to your instance via internet or do you have a peering connection or using a private link?

Comment: How do I resolve inside a container pod? I connect via internet using the `mongo+srv://` connection string.

Comment: You have a hostname, yo should try to resolve DNS with tools like dig or nslookup.
Also yo can instantiate a POD you want to perform the test from a different container in case your container doesn't have the necessary tools

Comment: Inside a pod. I pinged 1.1.1.1 and google.com it worked. I tried to curl compass from downloads.mongodb.com and it said host not found. Could it be a dns issue?

Comment: Check out POD's DNS servers with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
If I try to resolve your mongo servers with 1.1.1.1 DNS server, it works.
Which K8s flavor are you using. GKE, EKS, AKS ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with result of the command. Pls check. I'm using k3s

Comment: I really wanted to know if you are running on any public cloud provider.
Use that DNS server you found to perform DNS tests

Comment: It's from a personally owned server with a static ip purchased from ISP. Can I change the dns to 1.1.1.1?

Comment: It doesn't matter what DNS are you using but be sure your DNS is able to resolve the public mongo DNS entries.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Pls shed some light.

Comment: dig @dnsserver hostname .Also I would try executing the container in your laptop, out of k8s

Comment: Out of k8s it works. I don't understand what you mean by dig @dnsserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this after almost 20 days of struggle. The issue was the nameserver of my host was default `172.x.x.x` IP. I changed it to `8.8.8.8` and restarted the pod and it connected.

I didn't bother it initially because it worked from the development environment on the host from VSCode and Docker containers. I don't really understand this behavior.

Maybe a correct nameserver can fix a lot of things.