# Cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas from NodeJS in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, networking, minikube

When trying to connect to a MongoDB shared cluster instance from the NodeJS MongoDB driver, everything works fine when running the code normally or in the Docker container, but fails as soon as the container is inside the K8s cluster.

```
[INFO] 03:51:42 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.2.2)
AJKLJKLASDHFSUIEHFSUIEKFSJKDFJKS
(node:32) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Listening on port 3000!!!!!!!!
Error: Failed to connect to Mongo
    at /app/common/dist/mongo-wrapper/mongo-singleton.js:26:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[ERROR] 03:52:14 Error: Failed to connect to Mongo
```

[MongoDB Atlas not connecting from Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053973/mongodb-atlas-not-connecting-from-kubernetes) is very relevant but I tried changing the /etc/resolv.conf to have the nameserver as 8.8.8.8 and it did not work. Here is the results of nslookup from within the pod, both before and after I changed resolv.conf:

```
/app/auth # nslookup "mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/"
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

** server can't find mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/: SERVFAIL

** server can't find mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/: SERVFAIL

/app/auth # vi /etc/resolv.conf 
/app/auth # nslookup "mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/"
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8:53

** server can't find mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/: NXDOMAIN
```

Here are other things that I have tried:

- Running nslookup on other sites such as google.com and reached them appropriately.
- Running the code normally using npm run start properly connects to MongoDB.
- Packaging the code using Docker and running it from there, it connects properly to MongoDB.
- Adding ?authSource=admin to the end of the connection URL as proposed by https://groups.google.com/g/reactivemongo/c/bmjLQgM5b84?pli=1

I also tested using mongosh to connect directly. I made a new pod on my Kubernetes cluster with the mongo image and tried connecting from there. To my surprise that actually works. but I need to be able to use it from within NodeJS. Here are the logs from that pod:

```
root@mongo:/# mongosh "mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/" --apiVersion 1 --username <Myusername>
Enter password: ****************
Current Mongosh Log ID: 654471b1af0ab68af8925ed2
Connecting to:          mongodb+srv://<credentials>@2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/?appName=mongosh+2.0.1
Using MongoDB:          6.0.11 (API Version 1)
Using Mongosh:          2.0.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

Atlas atlas-o3cf3e-shard-0 [primary] test> exit

root@mongo:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local lan
options ndots:5

root@mongo:/# nslookup "mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/"
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

** server can't find mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/.lan: SERVFAIL
```

If this is a Kubernetes problem I am confused as to why the mongo image works but my does not. My image is the latest node:alpine image. The cluster I am running is minikube. If this is a networking issue I don't see why the runs of the Docker container outside K8s on the same machine would be any different than those running inside the cluster. I am incredibly lost here and some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't `nslookup https://www.google.com/` but instead `nslookup www.google.com`, do you? Similarly, don't `nslookup mongodb+srv://2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net/` but just `nslookup 2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net`

Comment: For SRV lookups you need to modify a bit: `nslookup -type=srv _mongodb._tcp.2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net` and for the TXT record: `nslookup -type=txt 2stepdevcluster.l2lhszy.mongodb.net`

Comment: Or try plan B: get the legacy connection string from Atlas that starts with "mongodb://"